# Restoring changes boolean true to false

Tags: c#, mysql

In my program there is method which takes backup as this:

```
INSERT INTO `vente` VALUES('1','101','Mehdi','Ismail','3','107','Serpina'
,'1','Ephese','3','1','0','0','2014-05-20','0615','Pacha','9','0','60','0','0',
'False','True','1','5','1',
'2014-07-02 05:14:45','1','2015-01-05 03:17:47')
```

When I restore, True fields are stored ZERO

I read the CSV file with StreamReader and use the command ExecutNonQuery()

The column is designed as bool in mysql 5.5.

During the restoration is this field transformed to a string ?

If I use LOAD DATA INFILE instead of my method this can resolve this problem ?

Here is my method which restores the data (It's a little bit long but however some are asking to see what I have done for this)

```
    private void RestoreData()
    {
       // some declaration for labels and textboxes
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(pathname);
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.sql");
        if (Files.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no sql files in this folder.");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; ++i)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathname, Files[i].ToString());
            TotalRows = TotalRows + File.ReadAllLines(filename).Length;
            MyArray[i] = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Length.ToString();
        }
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; ++i)
            {
                string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathname, Files[i].ToString());
                string tblname = Files[i].ToString();
                tblname = tblname.Substring(0, tblname.Length - 4);
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Would you restore the table " + tblname + " ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                MySqlCommand cmd;
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tblname, conn);
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString() + " -> " + e.Message.ToString());
                        conn.Close();
                        button5.Visible = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    int RowsNbr = Convert.ToInt32(MyArray[i]);
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8, true);
                    for (int a = 0; a < RowsNbr; ++a)
                    {
                        string cmdstr = file.ReadLine();
                        cmdstr = cmdstr.Replace("\n\r", string.Empty);
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString() + " -> " + e.Message.ToString());
                            button5.Visible = true;
                            file.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        ++counter;
                        int barvalue = (counter * 100 / TotalRows);
                        progressBar1.Value = barvalue;
                        barproceed = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!barproceed)
                {
                    counter = counter + Convert.ToInt32(MyArray[i]);
                    int bar1value = (counter * 100) / TotalRows;
                    progressBar1.Value = bar1value;
                }
                barproceed = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: csv has no "types". EVERYTHING in a csv is a string. What is the type of your "true fields"? A proper mysql bit is literally just `0` or `1`, representing false/true.

Comment: I told it. bool in mysql 5.5. During the backup I got the rows with true and false values.

Comment: and like I said, csv has no types. if you're using csv as your backup file, then you lose ALL type information and a mysql true/false will be written out as simple 1/0 integers.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking. I will change the column to smallint instead of bool.

Comment: why? `update foo set bitfield=1` will set the field to true, just as `... set bitfield=true` would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with a string value being interpreted in numeric context.

In the case of your INSERT statement, there's a string literal **`'True'`** that's being converted into integer. And MySQL doesn't throw an an exception or error when a string is non-numeric, MySQL gets whatever leading numeric value it can, and discards the rest. If MySQL can't find anything numeric, it evaluates to 0.  So, a lot of strings end up being evaluated as an integer value of 0.

A simple demonstration of string literals being evaluated in numeric context is to add a 0 to them:

```
SELECT d.d
     , d.d + 0
  FROM ( SELECT 'foo' AS d
          UNION ALL SELECT 'True'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'False' AS d
          UNION ALL SELECT 'a1'
          UNION ALL SELECT '123def'
          UNION ALL SELECT ' -12-345-67'
          UNION ALL SELECT '+42'
       ) d

d            d + 0  
-----------  ------
foo               0
True              0
False             0
a1                0
123def          123
 -12-345-67     -12
+42              42
```

We see that the string literal values `'True'` and `'False'` both evaluate to **0** in a numeric context.

OP states:

**The column is designed as bool in mysql 5.5.**

It's not clear what that means, because there is no "`BOOLEAN`" column datatype in MySQL 5.5.

MySQL does recognize the boolean literals **`TRUE`** and **`FALSE`**, but those are effectively just keywords that evaluate to integer values **`1`** and **`0`**.

Boolean literals are NOT enclosed in single quotes. Values enclosed in single quotes, e.g. **`'True'`** and **`'False'`**, are *string*  literals.

---

There are several possible mappings from a "boolean" to a MySQL datatype.

The dataype we always reserve for boolean is `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED COMMENT 'boolean'`.

We assign literal values 1 or 0, though it would be possible to also use the boolean keywords `TRUE` or `FALSE`. IF we assigned a string literal value of `'True'` (as MySQL allows), that would be converted to `0`, just like `'False'` gets converted to `0`.

Comment: Sorry for the version of mysql it's not 5.5 (it's the server' version) it's in my localhost and it's mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026.
As you told I will try to take the backup without single quotes for seeing the result.

Comment: @IsmailGunes: yes, the shorter answer might be to remove the single quotes from around `TRUE` and `FALSE` in your SQL statements, where you want those evaluated as integer values. (From your question, the datatype of the column is not clear... there's several possible ways (mappings) to store "boolean" type values in a MySQL column. We settled on always using `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED`; in database interactions, we just always handle that as an integer value.

Comment: Thank you I resolved with your idea not putting single quotes to boolean columns data. As I told from my phpmyadmin I can see a boolean type which puts the data as you told to tinyint 1